# What to do, If I asked low level question?

Tags: support, question-quality

I have [asked a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80240/40417), for which I could not find an answer on the internet. But after it got answered in one of the comments, I think that my question was a bit low level.

What should I do with my question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes things which are obvious in retrospect aren't obvious to everyone with a problem. Yours seems fine and it might help someone else. You mention that you couldn't easily find the info on the internet, and that may be the case for someone else in the future too -- except now the answer is here.

I'd suggest asking the person who provided the helpful comment which really answers the question to expand that into a full answer, and then mark that as accepted.